# "export '_supportsShadowDom' was not found in '@angular/cdk/platform'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, npm-install

I have install all necessary library to run angular app. But still build with error

```
"export '_supportsShadowDom' was not found in '@angular/cdk/platform'
```

I could not trace issues. What can I try next?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to install this version since Angular Material version is ^8.0.0:

```
install @angular/cdk 8.2.3
```

The version of Angular CDK must be lined up to the version of Angular Material.

Check this issue in [github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17209).

Comment: Even though this answer is slightly outdated, it helped me today. I needed to update @angular/cdk from 11.xx to 12.xx, as it was not automatically bumped by ng update migrations. The error that sounded similar as this question's author's went away after.

Comment: `npm i @angular/cdk@8.2.3` is the command to install 8.2.3 version.